# How to reset unity panel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, reset

When I click my setting icon its shows only name in menu. Please see the image

[image]

I already tried unity-reset, compiz reset method and unity reset icons.

Please provide a solution for this madness.

Comment: Why did you used the tag '13.04' on your question?

Comment: Sorry, It has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying this you might want to create another admin account just in case something happens.

This might be a solution, however, it is a bit inconvenient:
You could create a new directory in /home/ and call it for example 'home-backup'. Then move all your files of your home directory into 'home-backup' e.g. using nautilus as root (don't forget the .-files!)

Then you can just logout and login and everything should be like it was.
(Note: unless you don't copy some files from 'home-backup' e.g. your browser will also be like it was after you installed your system)